# php session login not display any change on login top bar

Tags: php

I am surprised to see my top login bar cannot show any change after user login.
Other element of in this bar like logo, decorative div show as it but after 'login to change username' & 'registration to change logout' & 'all notification' display like I am not logged in.

I cannot understand where is my wrong. It cannot show any error also.

Please see my code:

Included my every pages:

```
<?php include_once("top_login.php"); ?>
```

my top_login.php

```
<?php include_once("login/session.php"); ?>
<div id="toplogin">
<div class="logintext1">
<?
if($session->logged_in){
echo '<a class="logintext" href=../login/myprocess.php>Logout</a>';
} else {
echo '<a class="logintext"  href="../login/regis.php">Register</a>';
}
?>
</div>
<div class="logintext2">
<?
if($session->logged_in){
echo '<a class="logintext"     href="../login/mn.php">'.$_SESSION["username"].'</a>';
} else {
echo '<a class="logintext" href="../login/mn.php">Log In</a>';
}
?>
</div>

<div class="logintext3">
<?
if($session->logged_in){
echo '<a class="logintext" href="#"><img style="padding:2px 2px"  src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/nof2.png" /></a>';
} else {
echo '<a class="logintext" href="../login/mn.php"><img     style="padding:2px 2px" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/nof.png" />    </a>';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can find solution by using `print_r($session);`

Comment: Are you doing your session_start() stuff?. Also, see what Rohan Kumar said above.

Comment: i would guess youre not starting the session in the pages that have the include.  As @TheMarlboroMan said.

Comment: session_start(); not work also. I have more than 100+ page. few of pages its work well without session_start();. Thank u

Comment: If i add www. my top bar not work, but without www. its work well. where is my problem please.

Comment: The information you're providing is not enough to come up with the solution. Please, try dumping your session data through print_r. Also, the session for www.yoursite.net is handled separatedly that the session for yoursite.net or mirror.yoursite.net: double check where you`re sending the login data.